# Using LIKE in SQL to find two values in 1 string in 1 column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a like statement to find two strings in 1 column, ie.

- Table name is `CustomerNumber`
- Column name is `ID`

Sample strings  in column `ID` would be:

```
12345678909876543210
98765432109876543210
```

I want to find the row that contains 456 and 654.

My SQL statement is:

```
Select * 
from CustomerNumber 
where ID like all (values ('%456%'), (%654%'))
```

But I am getting expression errors.

Comment: What **datatype** is your column `ID` ?? `LIKE` can only be applied to string (`(n)char` or `(n)varchar`) columns

Answer (score 2):

You can use `like`:

```
select cn.*
from customernumber cn
where cn.id like '%456%' and cn.id like '%654%';
```

If you want them in a particular order, then use one `like` pattern:

```
select cn.*
from customernumber cn
where cn.id like '%456%654%';
```

I have never seen the construct `like all` nor `like` with a subquery that returns multiple rows.  I imagine that generates a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM CustomerNumber
WHERE ID like '%456%' AND ID like %654%'
```

Comment: @BradJarrett happy to help! dunno why someone downvoted anyway